# How to write nested list in boost property tree and dump it as json?

Tags: c++, json, boost

I want to use a nested list in boost json. What I want is like

```
{"matrix": [[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]}
```

I couldn't find the nested list case in the [official document](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/property_tree/parsers.html#property_tree.parsers.json_parser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document is not very detailed about create list value, I have tried to accomplish it, we need to call `put` with empty path, and `push_back` with empty path

```cpp
int main() {
  pt::ptree child_inner1;
  pt::ptree child_inner2;
  child_inner1.put("", 0.0);
  child_inner2.put("", 0.0);

  pt::ptree child;
  child.push_back(std::make_pair("", child_inner1));
  child.push_back(std::make_pair("", child_inner2));

  pt::ptree sub;
  sub.push_back(std::make_pair("", child));
  sub.push_back(std::make_pair("", child));

  pt::ptree tree;
  tree.add_child("matrix", sub);

  std::ostringstream oss;
  pt::write_json(oss, tree);
  std::cout << oss.str();

  return 0;
}
```

[Online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fndYvTKPY)

The code is somewhat ugly. So I suggest using other JSON libraries to generate the JSON. Since you are using boost, the recent version of boost already have a JSON library that is super fast, and with modern design, it would be a good start: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/json/doc/html/index.html